# Help with a jQuery selector

Tags: jquery

```
 <div class="divorder">     
     <table class="formfieldsmall">       
        <tr>
           <td style="width: 2%;">
               <img class="trigger" src="/SPLockerWebApp/Assets/themes/default/images/plus.png" />               
           </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
</div>
```

I need to change the image, but the following is not working in IE:

```
$(this).children()[0].children[0].all[2].src
```

Can anybody tell me the right option?  I have bind click event on divorder.

`$(this).next("trigger").src` like this

Comment: Put some effort into your question, or nobody is going to be bothered answering it. Explain in more than 3 lines what the problem is, what the code looks like, and maybe post a link to a online version that shows the problem.

Comment: He wrote much enough I think:
`I need to change the image`
and gave us some code
`$(this).next("trigger").src`
It's quite easy to understand what he needs. But you're right anyway. He could write more about his problem so that everybody understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be better off using the find method

```
$('.divorder').click(function(){
  $(this).find('img.trigger').attr({src: 'some/image/path.png'});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).next("trigger").attr("src", "some/path/to/image.png");
```